# How can we assign task to dynamic approvers in Sharepoint Workflow using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am trying to design a workflow based on grading system ....For example, each user have a grade defined in a master list , accordingly will loop in to assign task to dynamic approvers...i.e. for L3 grade flow will loop for 3 times to assign task to 3 dynamic approvers in series, for L2 grade flow will loop for 2 times...This grade and count will maintained in master list A....

Please suggest any workaround for the same...

Answer (score 0):

The OOB task process in SharePoint Designer workflow accepts a user retrieved by the workflow using lookup. If you want to use dynamic approvers in a workflow, you can select "Workflow Lookup for a User" and point to the Approvers filed in the master list.

Reference: [SharePoint – Custom approval workflow with Dynamic Approvers using SharePoint Designer.](https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/)

Please note, if you build a workflow based on the master list, the workflow cannot loop on multiple items but only current item which the workflow instance is attached to. As a workaround, you can send one approval task to all users with the same grade, all responses required.